# How to insert HTML tags in Joomla! module title?

Tags: php, html, joomla, trim

What I'm trying to do is to add some HTML tags to my Joomla! module titles. I will need something like this

```
Some <b>Title</b>
```

but when I save !Joomla trims the titles and remove all HTML tags.

I've check the administrator/com_content, which I think should be responsible for inserting the database data, but I couldn't find the answer there.

Can anyone help me with this headache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found the solutions. It includes both of the previous answers, so I'm putting a new one here with the correct code.

First of all I need to say, that this solution works only for a fixed amount of words (last one, two, etc.) I need only to have the last one, so I will post an example code with one word.

First as **SMacFadyen** sad I needed to create a new module structure in my template html folder: /templates/system/html/modules.php file.

*Note: If you don't want to add this new module styling to all templates, but just on one of them you need to put the module.php in your template's html folder.*

The provided by **SMacFadyen** looks like this:

```
function modChrome_myCustomModule($module, &$params, &$attribs)
{
$doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
$css  = ".otherClass {}";
$css .= ".yourClass {}";

$doc->addStyleDeclaration($css);

?>
    <div>
        <?php if ($module->showtitle != 0) : ?>
            <h1><?php echo $module->title; ?></h1>
    <?php endif; ?> // post your title
    </div>
    <div>
         <?php echo $module->content; ?> // post your module content
    </div>

<?php
}
```

Then expired by the comments of **Hanny** I've added some php code to match the last word of the title and to store it in a new varibale.The code looks like this:

```
$wrap_tag = 'b';
$html_title = preg_replace("~\W\w+\s*$~", '<'.$wrap_tag.'>'.'\\0'.'</'.$wrap_tag.'>', $module->title);
```

*Note: the `$wrap_tag` variable stores the tag you want. You can put b, em, u and etc. to have different result.*

The last thing was to replace the displayed title, so I've replaced this code:
`<h1><?php echo $module->title; ?></h1>`
with this one:
`<h1><?php echo $html_title; ?></h1>`

**The final result was this:**

```
function modChrome_myCustomModule($module, &$params, &$attribs)
{
$doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
$css  = ".otherClass {}";
$css .= ".yourClass {}";

$wrap_tag = 'b';
$html_title = preg_replace("~\W\w+\s*$~", '<'.$wrap_tag.'>'.'\\0'.'</'.$wrap_tag.'>', $module->title);

$doc->addStyleDeclaration($css);

?>
    <div>
        <?php if ($module->showtitle != 0) : ?>
            <h1><?php echo $html_title; ?></h1>
    <?php endif; ?> // post your title
    </div>
    <div>
         <?php echo $module->content; ?> // post your module content
    </div>

<?php
}
```

**Thanks to everybody for the help.**

Answer (score 4):

Check out ../templates/system/html/modules.php

You can style your module structure in HTML.

```
function modChrome_myCustomModule($module, &$params, &$attribs)
{
$doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
$css  = ".otherClass {}";
$css .= ".yourClass {}";

$doc->addStyleDeclaration($css);

?>
    <div>
        <?php if ($module->showtitle != 0) : ?>
            <h1><?php echo $module->title; ?></h1>
    <?php endif; ?> // post your title
    </div>
    <div>
         <?php echo $module->content; ?> // post your module content
    </div>

<?php
}
```

Then call your styled module in index.php:

```
  <jdoc:include type="modules" name="right" style="myCustomModule"  />
```

Comment: I'm familiar with this, but it doesn't fit the thing i want to accomplish. In the way you described I can achieve something like this: `<h1><b><?php echo $module->title; ?></b></h1>`, which outputs `<h1><b>Some Title</b></h1>` What i need is `<h1>Some <b>Title</b></h1>`.

Comment: Right, I see. Can't you just use CSS3 for this? :last-child or something.

Comment: You could add specific CSS to the custom module and use absolute positioning with differnet span classes to get your style choices.

Comment: I cannot think of a CSS solution which can help me do this. Can you post a suggestion how to do it?

Comment: h1:last-child {
    font-weight: bold;
   }

Comment: or for browser support like Ie6,7 and Safari use CSS: h1 span { font-weight: bold; } and then HTML: <h1>Some <span>Title</span> </h1>

Comment: Yes, but this will grab ha last h1 inside the container and it will make it **whole of it** bold. What i want is to have only the **last word** (or last 2 words) bold.

Comment: That is the problem. I cannot change the markup, because Joomla! strips the tags when saving to the database.

Comment: Unfortunately disabling/changing the editor affects only the content area. It is not connected to the module title in any way. If it was an article, or a mod_custom it would work, by adding the title in the content, but for other mother it is impossible to use that.

Comment: I found a solution, which includes both of the answers for this question so I will put another answer below including both.

Answer (score 1):

The Gantry framework can help you accomplish what you want (1st word styled one way, 2nd word styled another) - but it's a lot of overhead just accomplish that one task you're looking for.  Ultimately you'll have to create a template override for your template, and then do some creative editing with php in order to get it to display that way.

There's no quick and easy way to get that done.  You'll have to do some php coding on the backend and edit the template (use an override so you don't hack core files).  Ultimately you'll probably have to code the php to pull apart the title, and apply formatting to each pulled apart word (or string of words as the case may be) using CSS.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking also for a PHP solution. In my mind the best way was to remove the tag stripping from the database insert/update function, but fist - i cannot find it and second - i need to do this in every update. I have a third solution in my mind - adding custom fields to the module XML and specify the title there. I don't know which one is the best. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should be able to pull up just the title (string of text) using the Joomla API - it shouldn't have any formatting associated with it but rather be a plain text string.  Then you can break it apart and have your template format it however you want with php.  Then it will all happen automagically anytime that template applies that rule to an article title.  That would be the best idea IMO and would work until you changed it.  If I'm going the wrong way with this I apologize, and please let me know.

Comment: You were right. I find a way to accomplish this. The solutions includes both of the answers of my question so I will put a new answer with the correct code. Thanks a lot!